# Rails send a form to server for validation before commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a fairly detailed Rails form (`<%= form_for(@pay_line) do |f| %>`) that takes multiple values input by the user.

I need to check a number of things on this form before I commit the values to the database (such as the net pay is not a negative etc.). I'd normally use jQuery but some of the calculations are very detailed and rely on join queries in the controller etc. so as far as I can see, it's not really an option.

I'm wondering how I should go about this. Is there a way to send the form to the database for processing before committing and if certain things fail, send the values back with a message saying certain things need to be adjusted by the user? Or is there another option I can use?

Hopefully I've explained it properly but if I haven't, let me know and I'll give more details.

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [ActiveRecord::Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

It allows you to run some validations on a model before committing the changes to the database, and access to the errors when the model is invalid:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end

>> p = Person.new
# => #<Person id: nil, name: nil>
>> p.errors.messages
# => {}

>> p.valid?
# => false
>> p.errors.messages
# => {name:["can't be blank"]}
```

Assuming you want to edit a `Person`, save its changes or display its errors
when the changes are invalid, you could do something like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
YourApp.routes.draw do
  resources :persons, only: [ :edit, :update ]
  # This generates requests :
  #   GET '/persons/1/edit' (used to display the form)
  #   POST '/persons/1 (used to save the changes)
end

# app/controllers/persons_controller.rb
class PersonsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    # used to display the edit form
  end
  def update
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    if @person.update_attributes(params[:person])
      # the changes are valid, here we simply redirect
      # to the home page
      redirect_to(root_path)
    else
      # the changes are invalid, we display the form
      # again
      render :edit
  end
end
```

The edit view will display both the person form and its possible errors :

```
<%# app/views/persons/edit.html.erb %>
<% if @person.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @person.errors.full_messages.each do |error_message| %>
      <li><%= error_message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
<%= form_for(@person) do %>
  <%# your custom form fields %>  
<% end %>
```

Notice the example above generates page reload when submitting the form.

To prevent this, you might use **Ajax requests** to send the form in JS to the Rails server. In this case, the Rails server could render **JSON** instead of HTML.

Comment: I'll look into this thanks. How would I go about returning the possible errors to the JS. Does it come back to the client as an array? If so, how do I handle it on the client side. I'm going to have to look for a few tutorials

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how this could be achieved without JS. If you need complex JS behavior, you might use ajax requests & json server responses.

Comment: Thanks a million for this. Will try implement it in my code this week

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) for more complex validation.

To validate net pay:

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless record.net_pay > 0
      record.errors[:name] << 'Net pay must be greater than 0!'
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm a bit lost on how I implement that. Does the form get submitted and processed then validated. And if successful committed? Or if unsuccessful rolled back? I'm going to look for some tutorials

Comment: If the data sent to the model fails validation, it doesn't get saved; the client gets a 400 or 422 http response code (a client error).

Comment: Ok I'll look into this, thanks. My form updates or creates multiple objects across different models but I'll try hack something together